# GET $.cookie Expires Datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a date in $ .cookie expires in the format:

```
"2016-11-12T02:18:31.000Z" (ex: expires: date)
```

How to read in the format:

```
"Y/m/d H:i:s" (ex: expires: date)
```

My cookie jQuery:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie('myCookie', 'yes', {
    expires: date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) is a separate plugin. You need to load that explicitly using a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I want to read the date.setTime "2016-11-12T02: 18: 31.000Z" in the format "Y / m / d H: i: s"